# Easiest way to find (or approximate) x that gives maximum y of this function

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

I'm trying to find  $x$, $x>0$ that maximizes a relatively complicated function $f_n$.

The function $f_n$  is defined as:

$f_n=C_{n,1}-\frac{C_{n,2}}{C_{n,3}-\frac{C_{n,4}}{C_{n,5}-f_{n-1}}} - x$

Where:

$f_{n-1} = C_{n-1}-\frac{C_{n-1,2}}{C_{n-1,3}-\frac{C_{n-1,4}}{C_{n-1,5}-f_{n-2}}}$

...

$f_0=C_{0,1}-\frac{C_{0,1}}{C_{0,2}-\frac{C_{0,3}}{C_{0,4}-x}}$

${C_{n,i}}$ are constants, ${C_{n,i}}>0$, $n\geq0$.

One way to do it is to find the derivative and solve for $x$. It's relatively easy for $f_0$, harder for large $n$.

Another method is to use golden section search. It is appropriate for my use case (solving the problem programatically), but it requires a specified interval, and in my case that's $[0, \infty >$.

I'm hoping someone more experienced could point me to the right direction. Is there a good way to approach this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *a relatively complicated function* is, I presume, an understatement.

Comment: You can easily find that $f_0$ is decreasing function of $x$, $f_1$ is increasing function of $x$, $f_2$ is decreasing function of $x$ and so on. If $n$ is even, then $f_n$ is decreasing function of $x$ and it's maximum corresponds to minimal possible $x$. If $n$ is odd, then $f_n$ is difference of two increasing functions of $x$. That makes search of global maximum difficult, because potentially there can be many local maximums.